# kill a html page after re-direct

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form in one webpage ,say 'page-1'.

When the user clicks the submit button of the form,it executes a PHP script and displays another page, say 'page-kill'.

In that page kill I have used,

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1,URL=myURL">;
```

to redirect to another page. I want the 'page-kill' to be completely closed after redirecting to  'myURL' . that is, after showing 'myURL' ,pressing the browser back button should not show the 'page-kill'.

Is there any best/simple way to do it?

Comment: you can prevent the page from being cached and use referrer property to check if you'll be  going back to 'page kill' page or not and then prevent it.

Comment: keep the button click as session data and if it is clicked in the same session the user will be redirected to desired page when ever he will try to access the button  clicked page.what psylogic has said is also a great way, I have never used any of it .

Comment: _"browser back button should not show the 'page-kill'."_ What should be displayed if user clicks back button ?

Comment: there might be a design flaw here, why not just go from page-1 to myURL?are you modularising your code?

Comment: You can use `location.replace` - see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace).  The intermediate page (why is there anyhow?) will not be saved in the session history.